# Batch file to output the list of files from a directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find, dir

I am trying to find the latest log file from the log directory in windows which has sub folders based on date

I have to make a search of 1000+ keywords in a text file and find the match using the file name in keyword and output the path to a notepad

```
Example:

The source text file has many rows like 

Apple
Mango
Orange
```

Then we have to find the matching file like

```
 FF_Apple_201502.txt ( Latest one among the results )
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: not sure, what you exactly want, but it sounds like a job for `findstr /m /g`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below to find the latest file:

```html
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b *.*') do set recent=%%x
echo %recent%
```

then when you have the file you can pipe it into find:

```
FIND [/V] [/C] [/N] [/I] "string" [pathname(s)]
```

You can find the switch commands here:
ss64.com/nt/find.html